# fileupload not working on window.showModalDialog

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, modal-dialog

I am looking to open a aspx page to act an an image uploader.. this is the code I use to open the page:

```
$("#btnUpload").on("click", function (s) {
    s.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#hdnId').val();
    var response = window.showModalDialog("/imageUpload.aspx/", id);
    alert(response);
});
```

the page opens fine and looks like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <label>Choose New Image:</label>
            <br/>

            <asp:FileUpload ID="imageUploader" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>

            <asp:Button id="UploadButton" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" Text="Upload file" runat="server"></asp:Button>     
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The fileupload renders ok on the page - but the choose file button doesn't work at all! ive watched in chrome & there are no jquery errors on page load or on click of the choose file button.

I've done a bit of googling and found that ajax and update panels are dodge with the fileuploader - But i'm not using either :-/

anyone know whats occurring here?? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact issue with the Chrome modal dialog. This is a Chrome v26 issue. You can take a look at following url for chrome bug tracker details.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225365

However they’ve fixed the defect but according to them it'll take up to 6 weeks to include fix into release. You can get the Chrome canary version to verify.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html